# give permissions to view private video

Tags: youtube-api

Can I use Youtube API to Insert and Drop e-mail addresses that are allowed to view a certain private video?

For example, I would like to register a friend's email through my website to view a private youtube video, then, after few days, remove this permission.

Comment: Who's private videos yours or his?

Comment: The private video is mine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate the user accessign any private video from your website. Make use of the OAuth 2.0 strategy to give permission to your friend. Please take a look at the following docs and videos to get a deeper insight.

- [OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)
- [Official Document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#standalone)
- [Step By Step Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJjQPaPAfWM)